# Assigning data from an anonymous handler ios

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I'm trying to get a reference of an NSArray that gets passed when I call sendAsyncrhonousRequest. Once I have that NSArray, I'd like to assign it to a class attribute but it seems I can't do that.

```
@implementation BarTableViewController {
    NSArray *_jsonArray;
}

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {

     NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

     if (statusCode == 200 && data.length > 0 && error == nil)
     {
         NSError *e = nil;
         NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

         if (!jsonArray) {
             NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
         } else {
             _jsonArray = jsonArray; // this doesn't work? _jsonArray is at the class level
         }
     }
     else if (error)
     {
         NSLog(@"HTTP Status: %ld", (long)statusCode);
     }
     else if (statusCode != 200)
     {
         NSLog(@"HTTP Status: %ld", (long)statusCode);
     }
 }];
```

If I traverse jsonArray it will correctly display the data. If I assign it to _jsonArray to use it later, it no longer returns any data. The count of the array is zero.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _jsonArray.count; // always returns zero
}
```

How can I assign jsonArray to a class attribute so that I can use that data later?

Comment: Show your declaration of _jsonArray did you declare it weak? Can you show code that demonstrates how you try to read the array and find it empty? Is it empty, or nil? Also, your vocabulary is a little unique at least from my experience. They're usually called blocks, not anonymous handler; and usually we'd call that an instance variable rather than class level, and a property vs an attribute. Just a friendly tip.

Comment: I'm new to objective c / ios so my jargon is off, sorry about that. I've updated the question and provided what you asked for. When numberOfRowsInSection gets called, the count is always zero.

Comment: No problem :) are you certain it's the same instance that sets it vs that reads it?

Comment: What happens if you try '_jsonArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:jsonArray];' instead?

Comment: hm. I think I know what the problem is. I think the UI is loading before the request completes. I guess my question should be, how can I repopulate a View Table?

Comment: @user1218776 it has a reloadData method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My theory was correct. The UI was loading before the request finished. What I did to fix this issue was to call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Inside the async request.

Answer (score 0):

Forget simple assignment:

```
 @implementation BarTableViewController {
   // NSArray *_jsonArray; forget it
}
```

instead own the object.

```
@interface BarTableViewController()
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSArray *jsonArray;
@end

/* --------- */

@implementation BarTableViewController
@syntethise jsonArray = _jsonArray;
@end
```

then to make it own it

```
 self.jsonArray = jsonArray; // will call synthesized setter
```

I'm assuming you are using ARC, because you get a nil value instead of a dangling pointer. Now you will get a valid jsonArray.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, my code looks much cleaner now. But it doesn't solve the issue. I think the problem is that the UI is being rendered before the async request has finished. If I replace that call with static data, it works correctly. I'm trying to figure out how to repopulate a Table View Controller first though.